# JavaFX: Problems with the the Stage show() method

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting lots of errors when trying to execute the show() method from JavaFX's Stage class. I am using Intellij IDEA. This is the base code generated by the IDE and I have been experiencing a lot of issues trying to set it up. I have been able to fix the other 10 errors I had to deal with but I cannot figure out how to fix this one.

This is my application class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/bin/java -p /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/usr/share/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar=46299:/usr/share/idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/giraffekey/Projects/jaff/out/production/jaff:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx-swt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.base.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.controls.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.fxml.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.graphics.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.media.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.swing.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/javafx/javafx.web.jar sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createTKStage(QuantumToolkit.java:600)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.doVisibleChanging(Stage.java:1154)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage$1.doVisibleChanging(Stage.java:182)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper.visibleChangingImpl(StageHelper.java:57)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.visibleChanging(WindowHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1064)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle, locale en_US
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1582)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:932)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.<clinit>(WindowStage.java:101)
    ... 21 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Might be a problem with your JavaFX SDK. Try to download a fresh copy from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ (make sure to download the right version for your platform). Also, check out the "Getting Started" guides at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/, particularly the one for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I have this Error lot of times.some time I rebuild the project again then not getting that error.